# Css hover on before element

Tags: jquery, css, html, selector

I have a div and a div:before. I want when the mouse goes over (hover) the :before element to change its color. Is there a way to do it no matter with css or jQuery?

I tried stuff like div:before:hover but nothing happened

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution 1

(doesn't resolve question) With just css:

```
span:before {
    color: red;
    content: "hi";
}
span:hover:before {
    color: blue;
}
```

html

```
<span>text</span>
```

edit: fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bwkM6/

### Solution 2

Work around for given problem without :before

http://jsfiddle.net/Z97uN/1/

Comment: This does not answer the question. The author wants a way to hover over the :before pseudo element and not over the span to change the :before pseudo element.

Comment: It works fine but the hover works on the while div (span) I want only when i go over "hi". Any other ideas ?

Comment: Not sure if you can because the :before doesn't really register in the dom as an element. Do you have a little more information about the situation to work around it ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z97uN/ I want the triangle in the top corner to change its color when when i go over it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z97uN/1/ how about that? Suitable work around without before?

Comment: I must agree this works perfect. The main reason I picked up this is because I'm in the middle of the project and I want every div witch class box to have that corner .. that's why I used before. If I don't find solution for my problem I'll pick this one. Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: No problem, I can see what you mean, but not sure if it's possible. If it is, I don't know it :>

Answer (score 2):

`:before` and `:after` pseudo classes cannot take on other pseudo-class attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine pseudo-elements quite like that, apparently. However, you can use jQuery to inject your "`:before`" element into the DOM, rather than doing it with CSS.

```js
$(function() {
    $('div.interesting').before('<div class="interesting-before"></div>');
});
```

Then in your CSS you just reference `.interesting-before` and `.interesting-before:hover` instead of `.interesting:before` and `.interesting:before:hover`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Z97uN/2/ for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I see several solutions:

EASIEST - you assign specific class to the div:before

```
//HTML
<div class="specificClass">A</div>
<div>B</div>
<style>
.specificClass:hover {color: red}
</style>
```

However from your question it seems you cannot do that. Then leverage jQuery:

Approach #1

```
//JAVASCRIPT
$("div").prev().addClass("specificClass");

//in your CSS 
.specificClass:hover {color:red}
```

Approach #2

```
//JAVASCRIPT
$("div").delegate($("div").prev(),"mouseenter mouseleave",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("specificClass");
}

//in your CSS 
.specificClass {color:red}
```

please note that you must understand that this will work only if there are only 2 divs. If there are more, all of them but the last will receive the ".specificClass." Anyway the same would happen if "span:hover:before" worked.

If you explain what and why you want to achieve what you describe we would be able to give better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
div:hover:before
{
//css here
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vijays90/aL4536zs/)